# Repeat function a couple times without for loop in python

Tags: python, functional-programming, tuples

Is there a way to quickly repeat a function (and generate a tuple) in Python 2?

I'm hoping the syntax looks something like:

```
x, y = repeat(fxn, 2)
```

where `fxn` takes no arguments and `2` is the length of the output tuple.

Comment: Why *"without for loop"*? What are you actually trying to achieve?

Comment: What's returned from the `fxn` function. A single value? A value different for every call?

Comment: What's wrong with `x, y = fxn(), fxn()`?

Comment: @jonrsharpe - I'm trying to avoid a for loop because I want a unique name for each of the variables.

Comment: @AndreaCorbellini - There's nothing wrong with `x, y = fxn(), fxn()`. I just don't want to repeat myself.

Comment: @dlask - I'm hoping we can consider the `fxn` function as a black box, but in reality it is `random.randint(0, 90)`

Comment: OK, a function that returns a single value. Then the answer of @Daniel is there for you.

Comment: But *why* do you want unique names, rather than e.g. a dictionary or list of values?

Comment: because I'll only have two or three variables, and it would be sort of tedious to have to refer to them as arr[0], arr[1], etc. when I could refer to them by more meaningful names.

Perhaps  I should have specified - I'm asking this question because I'm trying to make some code more readable. Functionally, what I want to achieve could easily be done with a for loop, but it might not be as readable.

Comment: When it comes to readability I suggest to follow the simplest possible approach: Two/three lines with a single assignment each.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use generator expressions:

```
x, y = (fxn() for _ in range(2))
```

Comment: How is this *"without for loop"*?

Comment: This is a generator expression and not a for-loop.

Comment: Given that you're still iterating over `range(2)` (as you would with `for _ in range(2): ...`) that's a bit of a distinction without a difference, isn't it?

Answer (score 3):

***Recursion approach***

If you insist you really want a `repeat` function which **repeatedly invokes a function at a given number of times** and **returns a tuple of all return values from all calls**, you may probably write in a recursion:

```
x, y = repeat(fxn, 2) #repeat fxn 2 times, accumulate the return tuples
```

So

```
def repeat(f,n):
   ret, n = (f(),), n-1
   if n>0:
       ret = ret + (repeat(f,n))
   return ret
```

**To test if it works**

Given you define a test function:

```
def F():
    return 'foo'
```

Test the repeat

```
a = repeat(F,1) # a <-- 'foo'
a, b = repeat(F,2) # a = 'foo', b = 'foo'
a, b, c, d, e = repeat(F,5) # returns tuples of ('foo','foo','foo','foo','foo') correctly
```

Bingo!

Answer (score 2):

Just one more way

```
import itertools
result = itertools.imap(lambda _:fxn(), range(0, 2)
```